# Can't call model to Django template

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to call an attribute from my model into my HTML template using Django. There is something strange going on as I am only able to call one of my two models into the template. Both models are working perfectly fine as far as I can tell by looking into my database. This is what my `models.py` looks like

```
class Respondez(models.Model):
responder = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='scores')
score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
class Meta:
    ordering = ['post_time']

def __str__(self):
    return self.score

class Profilez(models.Model):
    newuser = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.newuser
```

I am trying to call `Profilez`. **However, only `Respondez` can be called.** This is the view I'm calling from, which I simplified.

```
@login_required
def add(request):
    p = Profilez()
    z = Respondez()
    context = {
        'p' : p,
        'z' : z
    }
    return render(request, 'rating/add.html', context)
```

To test whether I can call my models, I have simple header tags in HTML for my template, `add.html`:

```
{% extends "rating/base.html" %}
{% block content%}

<h3> {{user.username}} </h3>
<h3> {{ z.post_time }}</h3>
<h3>{{ p.preference }}</h3>
```

No matter which attribute I call from the models, the line for `Respondez` works but nothing works for my `Profilez` model. This is despite the fact that my database has values saved for each attribute from both models.

I am getting inputs for `preference` from the following view on a separate template (first line won't paste with correct indentation), where users select 1 of 2 choices:

```
def onboarding2(request):
p = Prof()
p.newuser = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_opt = (request.POST['ob'])
    if selected_opt == 'mood':
        p.preference = 'mood'
    elif selected_opt == 'productivity':
        p.preference = 'productivity'
    else:
        return HttpResponse(400, 'Invalid form')

    p.save()

    return redirect('rating-onboarding3')

context = {
    'p' : p,
}
return render(request, 'rating/onboard2.html', context)
```

How can I accurately call my Profilez model? What's wrong here?

Comment: Is it just here, or do you have forgotten the indentation of the `class Respondez` block in your code too?

Comment: Ah sorry, it pasted over incorrectly but has the correct indentation in my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have instantiated `Profilez` with no parameters in the constructor, none of its fields get the initial value. Hence, `p.preference` also happens to be null. That is why `p.preference` is not visible in the template.

But, in case of `Respondez`, though you are still instantiating the object with no parameters, you still have given the default value of current time to `z.post_time`, so `z.post_time` is working.

If you want to access `p.preference`, you need to explicitly assign some value to `p.preference`, else how will the template show the value for something that doesn't have a value initialized in the first place? For instance, you could do `p = Profilez(preference='xyz')` while creating the object, and see what happens.

Also, if you want to fetch a specific entry from the database, then you need to do a **query**, rather than creating a new object. The syntax for creating query would be something like `Profilez.objects.get(newuser=some_random_user)`.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually using p.newuser just as an example to show that the Profilez model wouldn't load. The real attribute I'm trying to load is p.preference, which is a char field that I see is filled out in my database from a separate view.

I see it in my database, any idea why I am unable to call p.preference into the template? p.newuser is working smoothly now after you showed me that I was getting null values before!

Comment: @YusufA Seems like you are new to SO community. Please update your question with the actual code that didn't work, rather than a hypothetical code created to explain your scenario. I'll update my answer once I see where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: @YusufA, also, since you are doing `p = Profilez()`, you will not get anything for any fields in the `Profilez` model itself. The line `p = Profilez()` actually means to create a new instance of `Profilez`, and you haven't provided values for any fields, so all of them will be null. If you try `p = Profilez(preference='xyz')` instead, you will get `xyz` when you access `p.preference` in your template.

Comment: I should clarify, my question contains the real code I tried that didn't work. I was experimenting with both attributes in the Profilez model which weren't working for me, I see that I should have posted the question with the preference attribute instead as that is what I'm looking for. 
Thanks for clarifying! The xyz thing did work. I updated my question to show where users are submitting their preference before they reach this page. Is there a way outside of p = Profilez() to connect the template to users' submitted preference?

Comment: @YusufA by doing `p=Profilez()` you are creating an empty object. There is nothing inside it. If there is nothing inside, how can you expect for it to print `p.preference`? In case you want to print `p.preference`, you need to explicitly assign some value to `p.preference`. I have updated my answer, see above.